# Iterate over vector of vectors of Strings without using for loops in Julia

Tags: loops, vector, nlp, julia, array-broadcasting

Given a vector of vectors of strings, like:

```
sentences = [ ["Julia", "is", "1000x", "faster", "than", "Python!"], 
              ["Julia", "reads", "beautiful!"], 
              ["Python", "has", "600", "times", "more", "libraries"] 
]
```

I'm trying to filter out some tokens in each of them, *without losing the outer vector structure* (i.e., without flattening the vector down to a single list of tokens).

So far I've achieved this using a classic for loop:

```
number_of_alphabetical_tokens = []
number_of_long_tokens = []
total_tokens = []

for sent in sentences
    append!(number_of_alphabetical_tokens, length([token for token in sent if all(isletter, token)]))
    append!(number_of_long_words, length([token for token in sent if length(token) > 2]))
    append!(total_tokens, length(sent))
end

collect(zip(number_of_alphabetical_tokens, number_of_long_words, total_tokens))
```

output: (edited as per @shayan observation)

```
3-element Vector{Tuple{Any, Any, Any}}:
 (4, 5, 6)
 (2, 3, 3)
 (5, 6, 6)
```

This gets the job done, but it takes more time than I'd like (I have 6000+ documents, with thousands of sentences each...), and it looks a bit like an antipattern.

Is there a way of doing this with comprehensions or broadcasting (or any more performant method)?

Comment: If you are looking for optimal performance, first of all, then using loops is the most efficient solution. Trying to vectorize the code will very likely slow it down, perhaps dramatically. Julia loops are fast, 'vectorized' code are all loops, under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to avoid loops for performance reasons in Julia. Loops are fast, and vectorized code is just loops in disguise.

Here's an example of doing this with loops, and some reductions, like `all` and `count`:

```
function wordstats(sentences)
    out = Vector{NTuple{3, Int}}(undef, length(sentences))
    for (i, sent) in pairs(sentences)
        a = count(all(isletter, word) for word in sent)
        b = count(length(word)>2 for word in sent)
        c = length(sent)
        out[i] = (a, b, c)
    end
    return out
end
```

The above code is not optimized, for example, counting words longer than 2 can be improved, but it runs in approximately 700ns on my laptop, which is much faster than the vectorized solution.

**Edit:** Here's basically the same code, but using the `map do` syntax (so you don't have to figure out the return type):

```
function wordstats2(sentences)
    map(sentences) do sent
        a = count(all(isletter, word) for word in sent)
        b = count(length(word)>2 for word in sent)
        c = length(sent)
        return (a, b, c)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! @Shayan's answer works great as well, though at least in my PC there was no performance improvement. Your code is the fastest implementation so far (~50%-100% faster than my own attempt, especially using `wordstats2`), and it's also the more concise and readable code, so I'm marking this one as the accepted answer.

Comment: Quick follow-up question: How do you go from a document to the vector-of-vector-of-strings format? That seems like a potentially costly step that could be skipped.

Comment: Thank you for asking! After cleaning up the documents, I used `WordTokenizers.jl` to split the document in sentences, and the sentences into tokens. TBH I haven't tried it yet on the dataframe where I'm holding the documents, just on single documents. Any suggestions as to how to more effectively apply `nltk_word_tokenize`  to each sentence out of applying `split_sentences` to each document in a DataFrame?

Answer (score 3):

At first, I guess you have mistakes in writing the final results; for example, you wrote `7` for the number of total tokens in the first element of the `sentences` while it should be `6` actually.
You can follow such a procedure, fully vectorized:

```
julia> sentences = [ ["Julia", "is", "1000x", "faster", "than", "Python!"],
                     ["Julia", "reads", "beautiful!"],
                     ["Python", "has", "600", "times", "more", "libraries"]
                   ];

julia> function check_all_letter(str::String)
           all(isletter, str)
       end
check_all_letter (generic function with 1 method)

julia> all_letters = map(x->filter(y->check_all_letter.(y), x), sentences)
3-element Vector{Vector{String}}:
 ["Julia", "is", "faster", "than"]
 ["Julia", "reads"]
 ["Python", "has", "times", "more", "libraries"]

julia> length.(a)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 4
 2
 5
```

I can make a similar procedure for `number_of_long_words` and `total_tokens`. Wrapping all of it in a function, I'll have:

```
julia> function arbitrary_name(vec::Vector{Vector{String}})
           all_letters = map(x->filter(check_all_letter, x), sentences)
           long_words = map(x->filter(y->length.(y).>2, x), sentences)
           total_tokens = length.(sentences)

           return collect(zip( length.(all_letters),
                               length.(long_words),
                               total_tokens
                             )
                   )
       end
arbitrary_name (generic function with 1 methods)

julia> arbitrary_name(sentences)
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (4, 5, 6)
 (2, 3, 3)
 (5, 6, 6)
```

#### Additional explanation

When I write something like `length.(y).>2`, In fact, I'm trying to kinda chain some julia functions through vectorization. Consider this example to fully understand what is happening through `length.(y).>2`:

```
julia> vec = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

julia> lengths = length.(vec)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 3
 3

julia> more_than_two = lengths .> 2
3-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 1

# This is exactly equal to this:
julia> length.(vec).>2
3-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 1

# Or
julia> vec .|> length .|> x->~isless(x, 2)
3-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 1
```

I hope this help @fandak . I refer you to official doc for further explanation about [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting) and [chaining functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Function-composition-and-piping).

Comment: So cool! can you please explain about `length.(y).>2`?

Comment: @fandak, read **Additional explanation** in my answer.

Comment: `all(isletter.(collect(str)))` is quite inefficient, as it creates two intermediate arrays, and unnecessarily iterates over the entire word. It's better to do  `all(isletter, str)`

Comment: @DNF, I almost forgot the flexibility of `all`. Thanks for reminding me ❤️.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and for taking the time with the edits for additional explanations. Lots to learn from this one!. I accepted @DNF's answer as their code worked faster for me, but especially because (and this is entirely subjective) it looks and more understandable to my newbie eyes. Looking forward to learning more from your answers!

Comment: I think `map(x->filter(y->check_all_letter.(y), x), sentences)` has more layers than needed, the inner broadcast isn't doing anything. It can be just `map(x -> filter(check_all_letter, x), sentences)`. Likewise `y->length.(y).>2` has an extra dor, can be just `map(word->filter(str->length(str)>2, word), sentences)`.